# Content Experiment error - variation should be chosen before hit is sent to ga

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, content-experiments

I'm trying to set up a GA content experiment and see an error in the Chrome console that reads "Variations should be chosen before hit is sent to GA". The error only appears the first time I load the page before cookies are set. If I clear cookies and reload, it appears

It doesn't seem to cause any problems but am curious as to what it means. I posted in Google Forums but no one has explained it. Anyone here have any ideas?

Here's my code

```html
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=lYhtgjICSTGh0PEyfMA30w"></script>
<script>
var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
var pageVariations = [
  function() {
    $("#pdp_promo2").append($("#tagineBanner"));
    $('#tagineBanner').show();
  }, 
  function() { 
    $("#banner").attr('src', '/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/bnr_tagineB.jpg')
    $("#pdp_promo2").append($("#tagineBanner"));
    $('tagineBanner').show();        
  }
];
$(document).ready(
  pageVariations[chosenVariation]
); 
</script>
```

Comment: You choose the variation only after the DOM is complete. If installed as per documentation GA will track on page load. I guess if you put your code before the ga tag (without document.ready) the error will disappear.